# How is this algorithm working as expected? Despite the overflow

Tags: java, algorithm, language-agnostic, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to solve this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/closest-binary-search-tree-value/):

> Given a non-empty binary search tree and a target value, find the
>   value in the BST that is closest to the target.
>
> Note: Given target value is a floating point. You are guaranteed to
>   have only one unique value in the BST that is closest to the target.

This is a solution I saw posted online:

```
public int closestValue(TreeNode root, double target) { 
        int ret = root.val;
        while(root!=null) {
            if(Math.abs(target - root.val)  > Integer.MAX_VALUE){
                System.out.println( " Underflow!");
            }
            if(Math.abs(target - root.val) < Math.abs(target -ret)){
                ret = root.val;
            }
            root = (target < root.val)? root.left : root.right;
        }
        return ret;

    }
```

I'm considering the test case:

```
[1500000000,1400000000] 
-1500000000.0
```

where `1500000000` is the parent node and `1400000000` is the left child and  `-1500000000.0` is the target. Id expect the code to underflow in the Math.abs clause (which it does) because  `-1500000000 - 1500000000` is larger than Int.MIN_VALUE. But  I don't understand how the algorithm still returns `1400000000`.  Shouldn't the underflow cause the comparison to fail?

Comment: `target` is a `double`, so any expression involving it and an `int` is going to cause the `int` to be promoted to a `double`. This expression is not true in the first iteration of your loop: `Math.abs(target - root.val)  > Integer.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: @Aldert, added the target value.

Comment: @Selindek updated the problem with the problem statement with what I've gathered from 3rd parties that have copied the post verbatim.